# Must $A_\epsilon$ be convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $A \subset R^k  $ and let $ \epsilon \gt 0 $

Define : $$A_\epsilon = \{ x : A \cap  \overline{B}(x,\epsilon) \ne \emptyset \} $$

Suppose $A$ is convex, must $A_\epsilon$ also be?

So far I managed to show that if $A$ is either open or closed than so is $A_\epsilon$.

For the convex part i'm not sure.

I think it is not - for example if $A =[0,1] \cup [4,5]$ and $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

But, i'm not sure. Can anyone have a thought on this?

Comment: You example is irrelevant because your $A$ is not convex.

Comment: the set $A_\epsilon$ is convex if $A$ is convex.

Comment: @uniquesolution yea got it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the requirement that $A$ be convex. In your example $A=[0,1]\cup [4,5]$ and $\epsilon = 1/2$, $A$ is not convex. If $A$ is convex, then so will be $A_\epsilon$.

Here I'm assuming $\overline{B}(x,\epsilon)$ means the closure in $\mathbb{R}^k$, which is just the set $\{y\in \mathbb{R}^k:d(x,y)\leqslant \epsilon\}$. Then $x\in A_\epsilon$ if and only if there exists $u\in A$ with $d(x,u)\leqslant \epsilon$.

I'm also assuming the distance is Euclidean distance. Let $\|x\|$ be the Eucliean norm of $x$. That is, $\|x\|=d(x,0)$. Note that $\|ax\|=a\|x\|$ for positive $a$ and $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ for any $x,y$. The triangle inequality for $d$ is the same as saying $\|x+y\|\leqslant \|x\|+\|y\|$.

If $A$ is convex, then $A_\epsilon$ is also convex. Fix $0<\theta<1$ and $x,y\in A_\epsilon$. Let $z=\theta x+(1-\theta)y$. Since $x,y\in A_\epsilon$, there exist $u,v\in A$ with $d(x,u)\leqslant \epsilon$ and $d(y,v)\leqslant \epsilon$. Let $w=\theta u+(1-\theta)v$. Then $w\in A$ because $A$ is convex. Moreover,

\begin{align*} d(z,w) & =\|z-w\|=\|\theta(x-u)+(1-\theta)(y-v)\|\leqslant \|\theta(x-u)\|+\|(1-\theta)(y-v)\|\\ & =\theta\|x-u\|+(1-\theta)\|y-v\| = \theta d(x,u)+(1-\theta)d(y,v) \leqslant \theta \epsilon + (1-\theta)\epsilon = \epsilon.\end{align*} Thus $z\in A_\epsilon$ since $w\in A\cap \overline{B}(z,\epsilon)$.

Comment: Argh. now i see the problem with my example!

Comment: it's suppose to be $||z-w||$ instead of $||x-w||$

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it.